# Can a Schedule 40, 2" Double 1/4 Bend, All Hub, be used to in a horizontal position to drain two 2" PVC horizontal drain pipes?

Tags: plumbing

I have a washing machine and shower with 2" drain pipes that are both dry vented within 4 feet following their p-trap.

Can their horizontal runs feed into a horizontal 2" double 1/4 bend that then drains the water horizontally 114" before feeding onto a vertical 2" drain pipe that will meet up with the existing washing machine 2" stack pipe?

The existing stack pipe's p-trap is under the floor joist below and then enters the main sewer line 14" away through a 3" wye reducing 3x3x2 PVC.

Or do I need to use a horizontal 2" wye + 1/8 bend separately (left, right) for the washing machine and shower drain tie in?

Or horizontal combination wye & 18 bend [left and right]?

Or a horizontal double wye & 1/8 bend?

Or a horizontal 2" double eye capped 1 end + two 1/8 bends?

Also, there would be a horizontal long sweep 1/4 bend then 3-6" of 2" drain pipe, followed by a vertical long sweep 1/4 bend leading down to the existing washing mashing stack pipe.

I plan to use a rubber coupling to join the proposed 2" vertical drain pipe with the existing 2" stack pipe should future owners want to move washing machine back down to the first floor.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what that sentence fragment means, but if it's new information it should be in your question post, not down here.